# How can I configure environment variables in maven surefire per environment?

Tags: maven, bamboo, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run a maven test phase during a bamboo build plan. My tests rely on a set of environment variables that I configured in the pom.xml. However, those values are only applicable to one environment, and I would like to execute the same tests on multiple environments (different host IPS, etc). My Pom.xml looks something like this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.21.0</version>

<configuration>

 <environmentVariables>
    <variableName>variableValue</variableName>
  </environmentVariables>

</configuration>
```

The bamboo plan build has a stage which executes a maven test phase with a simple 'mvn clean test' command line. I have over 10 environment variables so I would like to ideally avoid to pass those variable values to the command line as it would make it very long. How can I configure maven surefire to include more than one set of environment variables (one for test, one for prod), such that I can then pass to a command line to pick up the environment variables depending on which bamboo build plan i execute. So something like: mvn clean -D test.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to tout question is to use profile filtering and properties file.
You need the following folder tree configured:

- src

  - test

    - java
    - profile-resources
    - resources

You need to put one properties file in resources, with variable values declared as links to the profile resources:
 variable={value}
and you need to create separate properties files in profile-resources for each environment.

Then include this in your pom.xml file:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Name of first profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <filter.properties>env1.properties</filter.properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Name of second profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <filter.properties>env2.properties</filter.properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/test/profile-resources/${filter.properties}</filter>
    </filters>
</build>
```

Then you can call each profile automatically with the -P Maven command which activates a profile.
Example: mvn verify -P "Name of profile".

Related resources:

- [Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Comment: Ok, first off thank you so much. I actually took this approach until I realized that I have no idea how I make a method in Java that would get an environment variable from the right file. I am using Java to get properties from a file on the classpath, so how would I load the correct class path file dynamically? Example of what I want to do can be found here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Using profile filters, your file is always called env.properties, but the actual env property files are called dev_env.properties, production_env.properties. Maven will make sure that when you select dev profile, the env.properties file loads its properties from dev_env.properties.
This is properties code:


    properties = new Properties();
  InputStream inputStream = null;
  try {
   inputStream = 
    PropertyUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/env.properties");
   properties.load(inputStream)

Comment: This is file structure:
[link](https://imgur.com/TO0aPue)

This is how env.properties looks:
property1=${property1}
property2=${property2}
property3=${property3}

This is how dev_env.properties look like:
property1=api.url
property2=website.url
property3=api.port

Maven will automatically load properties file based on the profile.
You always load the env.properties file in the code.

Comment: Thank you, so what would my env.properties file look like ? does this make sense: dev_env.properties - > hostname = devhost, prod_env.properties -> hostname = prodhost, env.properties -> hostname = ${hostname}?

Comment: Yes, that's it, you got it :D
In the env.properties file you just use a reference to the other properties in other files, congrats.

Comment: haha, i think we responded around the same time, I didn't see your answer but i'm glad it matches. thanks very much, i will try this soon!

Comment: You're very welcome, feel free to write to me if you run into hickups. We QA guys should stick together :D

Comment: Hi me again. After loading the properties using properties.load, how would I then assign final static variables to them? Does this work: public final static CONSTATNT_1 = System.getProperty("CONSTANT_1")?